# How do I change a Stripe Subscription's billing end cycle date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I am new to stripe but I will like to update stripe subscription billing current end date with ruby on rails or at least a suggestion on how to go about updating the billing end date.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea from here how to handle subscription billing periods

[Changing the billing cycle](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#changing)